# Extra JavaEmbeddedFrame window when using JDownloader

Tags: gnome-shell, jdownloader

I installed JDownloader in ubuntu 11.10 with gnome-shell. Everthing works perfect, but when I 'm using JDownloader, it also creates an additional "window" called JavaEmbeddedFrame (the app with the java logo without window in this [image: capture] , if you select it from the dash or from the alt+tab menú it shows nothing. How can I remove that window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JavaEmbeddedFrame` is a container for tray notification.

So if you don't want the empty window, disable `Light Tray` addon in your jDownloader settings.
If you used  to use minimize to tray, then try `Alltray` app.